# SQL split string and combine first and second occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a string as follows

```
Test1: Test Exp: Test3
```

I am trying to extract the string so that the output should be

```
Test1: Test Exp
```

I tried as follows

```
DECLARE @myString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Test1: Test Exp: Test3'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@myString,0,CHARINDEX(':',@myString,0)) AS firstPart,
SUBSTRING(@myString,CHARINDEX(':',@myString,0)+1,LEN(@myString)) AS secondPart
```

This gives output as

```
Test1 Test Exp: Test3
```

Comment: Expected output should be `Tes1: Test Exp` or `Test1: Test Exp`?

Comment: Sorry Test1: Test Exp some type mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `Test1: Test Ex`, you can do the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@myString, 0, LEN(@myString) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@myString)))
```

The part:

```
LEN(@myString) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@myString))
```

basically acts as `LastIndexOf(':')`

Answer (score 0):

If your expected output is `Test1: Test Exp`, then try following:

```
DECLARE @myString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Test1: Test Exp: Test3'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@myString,0,CHARINDEX(':',@myString,0)) AS firstPart,
       SUBSTRING(@myString,0,CHARINDEX(':',@myString,CHARINDEX(':',@myString,0)+1)) AS secondPart
```

I think you want to get the string before the second colon `:`

It can ignore the first colon and search second colon.

```
CHARINDEX(':',@myString,CHARINDEX(':',@myString,0)+1)
```